# How to write delete and create csv file in JavaScript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv

I am trying to create a application without the Database because I am not allowed to make a database for some reason. So I would need to delete a csv file then recreate a csv file with all of edited info in the csv file. I have all of the csv data in string but how would I be able to delete my current csv then create a new csv with with my csv string on the client's side?

Comment: browser-based JS has no file capabilities. you cannot read/write files on the client computer, as that'd be an incredibly huge/nasty security vulnerability.

Comment: You need to use server-side code. What server-side language are you using?

Comment: I am only using JavaScript with D3 within the app

Answer (score 0):

Outside of technologies like cookies, localStorage or IndexedDB, you can't affect the client's file system. A web page cannot automagically read/write a csv file. You would have to ask the user to download it.

Comment: what if I am able to set the csv in the backend/ in the repository. then have the user delete and create that csv file?

Comment: Additionally, @Hessvacio could also perhaps generate the data structure representing his CSV, and dump that into the page (possibly nicely formatted) so it can be copied by the user instead of downloaded. I've seen that done a number of times.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the in backend/repository. You said above you were only using javascript.

Comment: So @RaphaeldiSanto the only backend I have in the app is a csv file which holds all of the data to be plotted in the d3 portion of the app. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: ok @radicalmatt so you are saying after the edit form I should just represent the data in a popup page. That would be a great idea, however how would I show the changes on the csv file to show the changes in the d3's representation.

Comment: What I am saying is, putting the data onto the page is an easy way to get that data in the hands of the person looking for that data. 

I am inferring that you have a little more going on in your app than you are letting on. Could you explain in your question more about the Edit Form you mentioned? 

I imagine you have some data being entered by a user yes? You want the d3 vis to update and wherever the raw csv data is shown to update as well yes? All this is possible by handling events on your inputs. Tell us more in your question!